# Calculate Which Score is Higher (Value) Based on Name (Text)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to develop a way to calculate my football head to head matchups for my football league to show which team plays the best against each other. A snapshot of my spreadsheet is below:

Team names are in columns A and D, and their respective scores are in columns B and E.

[image]

So, I am wondering if there is a way to see if column B is greater than column E and then check to see what name is in the column to the left of the scores (column B/E) and then sort them into head to head records. For example, in the picture above, if I want to see Sam vs. Peyton's head to head record, it should be 0-2-0 (with the first value being a win, second is the loss column, and third are ties). Because in row 3 and row 6, Peyton scored more than Sam.

For Dan vs. Anthony it would be 0-1-0, 
and for Joe vs. Nick it is 1-1-0 and format it looking like this:

[image]

In the first spreadsheet, in cell F3, I tried to calculate the Sam vs. Peyton scenario, but could not get it to work properly.

If anyone has any advice on how to tackle this problem that would be awesome, because I have four years worth of this data and doing that by hand would not be fun!

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper columns in columns C and F that show the winner and loser of each match. In column C `=IF($B2>$E2,"W",IF($B2=$E2,"T","L"))` and in column F `=IF($C2="W","L",IF($C2="T","T","W"))` to find the win/loss/tie result of each match.

Then using a list of every player matchup (can be found using remove duplicates on both columns of names) put the player names in cells `H3` and `J3`.

Label columns `K`,`L`, and `M`  W, L and T respectively. Then, use a countifs formula that will count the number of wins losses and ties between the players. 
`=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$7,$H3,$A$2:$A$7,$J3,$F$2:$F$7,K$1)+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$H3,$D$2:$D$7,$J3,$C$2:$C$7,K$1))`

There are 2 countifs to account for the fact that sometimes Peyton will be in the first column and Sam in the second and sometimes it will be vice versa.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. I was able to create the helper columns in columns C and F so that they show W,L, or T. But now I am a bit confused when you said "using a list of every player matchup label the columns W, L, and T". In the countifs function you use the cells H3, J3, and K1 - am I supposed to put player names in these cells or W,L,T respectively? Because I tried those ways and it didn't work and I also tried putting the ```=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$7,$H3,$A$2:$A$7,$J3,$F$2:$F$7,K$1)+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$H3,$D$2:$D$7,$J3,$C$2:$C$7,K$1))``` function in those same cells and it returned 0 each time

Comment: `K1` has W, L or T and `H3` and `J3` has the player's names.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify some of the questions that you had. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Ok, thank you that makes a lot more sense than what I was previously thinking you meant :p thanks!